# TypeError CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, pg

I have a microservice that uses Postgres DB, and I am using sequelize in the project. Recently I have upgraded the node version from node10 to node14 and while doing that I have upgraded the sequelize to `4.42.0` and pg from 7.4.3 to 8.7.1, post-upgrade am facing below error without much information in stack trace except below two lines

```
TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object
  File "internal/timers.js", line 559, col 11, in listOnTimeout
  File "internal/timers.js", line 500, col 7, in processTimers
```

Any idea how to get more traces to know the exact issue ??

Comment: Can you paste the relevant part of timers.js?

Comment: If my assumption is correct timers.js is from node lib

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/9e0bba5648e9c4116b06a31afeb216bbba39c134/lib/internal/timers.js#L485

Comment: The error happens in that file. You need to paste the relevant part of the code into your question, as outside links and different versions are confusing the problem.

Comment: @LajosArpadi don't get what you meant by the relevant part ??

Since i don't have the stack trace where is the issue origin

Comment: Do you not have a timers.js?

Comment: Nope, I don't have such file in my project

Comment: According to the link you have provided, line 559 is `ReflectApply(timer._onTimeout, timer, args);`, see https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/9e0bba5648e9c4116b06a31afeb216bbba39c134/lib/internal/timers.js#L559.

Comment: yup, I can see that but which module/file/function called this processTimers function ??, i am trying to find the answer to this question. Once we find it then we can trace the route cause of the issue.

Comment: I think you will need to first find out which function is throwing this error and to see what the code of the function is. Generally the stack trace will be complete if you make main an async function and do an await on the method where the problem happens.

Comment: I used `process.on('uncaughtException', (exception, source)` but still hard luck, no stack trace. I couldn't able to find function since its not coming always

Comment: You can find the function by commenting out everything and upon each test uncomment a feature, until the problem reproduces. When the problem reproduces this way, you have managed to narrow the problem-space. Apply the same approach to the methods/lines of the feature as well.

Comment: unfortunately its huge project :(

Comment: Then apply binary search. Comment the second half. If the error still happens, then it is in the first half. If not, then it is in the second half. After you identified the problematic half, divide it with the same logic until you get to the problem. This is a logarithmic algorithm of problem search, so, if you have n features, then log(2, n) steps should suffice to find the actual error.